# MySQL UPDATE table with multiple JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, insert

I need to add some records to a table, but only those that match a certain linked table.
There are three tables are as follows:

```
extension_prefs (extension_id, value, parameter)
extension (id, client_id)
client (id, parent_client_id)
```

These will link as follows:

```
extension_prefs.extension_id = extension.id AND extension.client_id = client.id
```

I need to insert 4 records into `extension_prefs` for every extension belonging to a client with a specific `parent_client_id`. I have no idea of the syntax to achieve this although I have the feeling its quite straightforward.

EDIT: Yes I messed this up, these records need to be UPDATED not INSERTED.

Thanks very much

George

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the following query for each of the preferences and it will be saved for all the necessary extensions.

Updated:
The following query inserts a new row for the preference or if it exists then updates the existing one.
This assumes that the extension_prefs table has a unique constraint on the extension_id and parameter columns.

```
INSERT INTO extension_prefs (extension_id, parameter, value)
  SELECT e.id, "key", "value"
   FROM extension e
   JOIN client c ON e.client_id = c.id
   WHERE c.parent_client_id = 123
ON DUPLICATE KEY
  UPDATE value = "value"
```

Comment: It seems I have made a mistake, I need to update the records in extension_prefs as they already exist. How does this change the syntax?

Comment: You can add an "ON DUPLICATE KEY" clause to handle these
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Or does this mean that you only need to do updates, never inserts?

Comment: Yes sorry I think I made a mess of the original question. I should have said "I need to UPDATE a bunch of records in extension_prefs for all records in client with a certain parent_client_id". I figure this is much easier?

Comment: Could I do it like this? `UPDATE extension_prefs ep, extension e, client c
 SET ep.value = '8450342222'
 WHERE ep.extension_id = e.id AND e.client_id = c.id AND ep.param = 'someparam' AND c.parent_client_id = 952;`

Comment: Excellent thanks. Now it seems even more complex though - for some extensions I need to add the records, for others I need to update what is already there. I am thinking I should run the INSERT with the ON DUPLICATE KEY statement in addition to the UPDATE? Is there a way I can just make it skip records that already exist?

Comment: You don't need to run UPDATE separately if you use ON DUPLICATE KEY. Then you would basically define both the INSERT and UPDATE in the same query and the DB will choose which one it needs to use.
Of course this will only work if you have defined a unique constraint on the extension_prefs table using both extension_id and parameter columns.